# Autogenerated primary key in postgresql which skips existing ones

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, generated

I have existing entries in a table with primary keys starting with 300 and ending at 400.  Now I would like to insert new entries with an auto generated primary key. The generation should skip the existing ones. Is there an easier way to do this instead of using triggers or a key table?

Answer (score 0):

if you didnt change the seed, the news rows will continue from 401 so shouldnt be any problem

But if you want change it use **[ALTER SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altersequence.html)**:

```
 ALTER SEQUENCE yourTable_something_seq RESTART 500;
```

Comment: But I need to do the restart manually, right? I want to do this autmomatically.

Comment: You shouldnt need restart, what you mean?

Comment: I didn't meant to restart the hole system, only the sequence with a new start value. I need a solution that the primary keys will be generated automatically and if a generated key is already used this one should be skipped.

Comment: You can start the sequence whatever you want. But after that, the sequence will give you a different number each time so you dont have to worry about that.